# When we define functions in a program, do they get stored in the standard library?

Tags: c, static-libraries, dynamic-library, c-libraries

Since there are two types of functions; Library functions and user-defined functions....when we define a function in a program, does that function get stored in the standard library just like the library functions?

Comment: Why do you think that? Did you try compiling the second time after omitting the function definition, since the definition may already be stored in the library ;-)

Comment: In the case of my code, I hope not:)

Answer (score 2):

No. User-defined functions are stored in the object file created by compiling. These are *linked* with the libraries containing C standard library functions to form an executable binary.

Answer (score 0):

Library functions are previously written and stored functions which we can use by calling them.
While user defined functions are written by the programmers based on their requirements, to use these functions first we have to define it and then we have to call it.
And when you define a function those are not going to be getting saved in standard library.

Answer (score 0):

When we `define` a function , it is not itself added to any library or object file. **YOU** need to create the object file [user functions] or library [static/dynamic] yourself. So. there is no concept of `get stored` as you asked. It entirely depends on what you are doing with your source code.

- If you are creating a library, **YES**, it will be a part of the
  library.
- If you are compiling to create an individual object file, **NO**, it
  will not be a part of any library.